# How to organize Spring Integration retry for a method with a list that decreases with every retry?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-retry

There is the following Spring Integration configuration with Retry:

```
<int:chain input-channel="sdCreationChannel" output-channel="debugLogger">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="500" />
    <int:filter ref="sdIntegrationExistingRequestSentFilter" method="filter"/>
    <int:service-activator ref="sdCreationServiceImpl" method="processMessage">
        <int:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <ref bean="retryAdvice"/>
        </int:request-handler-advice-chain>
    </int:service-activator>
</int:chain>

<bean id="retryAdvice" class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice" >
    <property name="retryTemplate">
        <bean class="org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate">
            <property name="backOffPolicy">
                <bean class="org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy">
                    <property name="initialInterval" value="${integration.retry.initial.delay}"/>
                    <property name="multiplier" value="${integration.retry.backoff.multiplier}"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="retryPolicy">
                <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy">
                    <property name="maxAttempts" value="${integration.retry.max.attempts}" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The simplified Java code is as follows:

```
@Component("sdCreationServiceImpl")
public class SDCreationServiceImpl implements SDCreationService {

@Autowired
private NotifySD  notifySD;
@Override
public void processMessage(IntegrationPayload integrationPayload) {
List<ConfirmationCode> sdConfCodes = findCodesFromPayLoad(integrationPayload);
    notifySD.activateConfirmationCodes(sdConfCodes);

}
```

The problem with retrying this code is that the List sdConfCodes can be partially processed at every Retry, so every time we need to send for processing the less amount of elements. What is best way to organize this code?

Following the Artem Bilan suggestion (Thanks!) I created the 2nd method with variable list in SDCreationServiceImpl, i.e. activateConfirmationCodes and then in the XML specification pointed to this method as a method for sdCreationServiceImpl.

```
@Component("sdCreationServiceImpl")
public class SDCreationServiceImpl implements SDCreationService {
@Autowired
private NotifySD  notifySD;
List<ConfirmationCode> sdConfCodes = new ArrayList<ConfirmationCode()>;
@Override
public void processMessage(IntegrationPayload integrationPayload) {
sdConfCodes = findCodesFromPayLoad(integrationPayload);
}  

public void activateConfirmationCodes()
{
    notifySD.activateConfirmationCodes(sdConfCodes);
}
```

And then the XML spec for service-activator is as follows:

```
<int:service-activator ref="sdCreationServiceImpl" method="activateConfirmationCodes">
<int:request-handler-advice-chain>
<ref bean="retryAdvice"/>
</int:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int:service-activator>
```

Yes, this method activateConfirmationCodes is invoked in Retry but the 1st method processMessage is not invoked at all. **Is it possible to specify one method for invoking at the first try and other method for retrying?**
Second with this design the list becomes the singleton and this can give problems in multithreading, correct?. Can this list be associated with a bean only for a particular message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From big it isn't clear where is your problem. From other side let me share some my thoughts, perhaps I will guess your goal.

Having the `List<ConfirmationCode>` as a `payload` allows us to modify it at any time. So, let's assume we have list as `10` elements. On the first attempt we have processed 3 of them. The fourth has failed. We have to go to retry throwing some appropriate exception.
But we come back to the beginning of the retry-aware method, so with the same arguments. If we remove those successful items from the collection, the next retry iteration won't process them at all.

From one side you can achieve that distinguishing `findCodesFromPayLoad()` service and `activateConfirmationCodes()`, applying retry for the last one.

From other side you can mark items as processed in the `activateConfirmationCodes()`, so the next `findCodesFromPayLoad(integrationPayload)` won't return them.

In other words there are enough ways to modify collection without changing messages.

Comment: Artem, great suggestion, but because I am a novice in SI I did not get the implementation details, please see editing

Comment: You must have two `service-actovator`s: First for the `findCodesFromPayLoad` and that one should return the desired `List<ConfirmationCode>` (but it is already now). And the second `service-activator` for the `activateConfirmationCodes` business method. But this one has to accept your `List<ConfirmationCode>` to process. The output `payload` of first service becomes the input `payload` of the next one. The retry must be applied for that service-activator which is with `List<ConfirmationCode>` argument.